# How to find the error in Python Lists program?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Getting an error as below:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "script.py", line 16, in 
> pizza_and_prices.sort()
> TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

My program is written like so:

```
    toppings = ['pepperoni', 'pineapple', 'cheese', 'sausage', 'olives', 'anchovie', 'mushrooms']

    prices = [2,6,1,3,2,7,2]

    num_two_dollar_slices = prices.count(2)
    num_pizzas = len(toppings)
    print('We sell ' + str(num_pizzas) + ' different kinds of pizza!')

    pizza_and_prices = prices + toppings

    print(pizza_and_prices)
    pizza_and_prices.sort()

    cheapest_pizza = pizza_and_prices[0]
    priciest_pizza = pizza_and_prices[-1]
    pizza_and_prices.pop()
    pizza_and_prices.append(2.5,'peppers')
    pizza_and_prices.sort()
    three_cheapest = pizza_and_prices[0:3]
    print(three_cheapest)
```

Comment: `pizza_and_prices` is a list containing both string and numeric values. Since strings and numbers (integers/floats) cannot be compared using `<`, Python raises an error.

Comment: You should make it a list of tuples: `pizza_and_prices = list(zip(prices, toppings))`

Comment: Remind me not to order from your pizza place, those are expensive anchovies. :)

Answer (score 1):

`pizza_and_prices = prices + toppings`

What happens when you run this is that it combines `prices` and `toppings` into one list

`[2, 6, 1, 3, 2, 7, 2, 'pepperoni', 'pineapple', 'cheese', 'sausage', 'olives', 'anchovie', 'mushrooms']`

This list now contains both integers and strings. In python, you can't compare int's to str's so you cannot sort a list that has both.

In this case `pizza_and_prices.sort()` will return an error.